# How to keep subview's position relative to its parent view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, ios7.1

I have a parent view (UIView), that contains 2 buttons (UIButton). These buttons are always on the bottom of the parent view. Now, when I make animation for the parent view (like increase its height), I want these 2 buttons should keep their previous relative position (should be on the bottom).

In the Size Inspector, I set the Origin of the button like

[image: inspector]

However, it doesn't work. Is there any simple solution for that? I don't want to write it in the code, because I have so many sub views, and want them keep their relative position in comparison to the parent view. Manually doing it in the code is really a hard work.

Note: I am using XCode 5, iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Xcode 5, you can use the new auto-layout buttons in IB:

[image]

You can then just pin your views to the bottom of the parent view in a similar way you would in the size inspector. You may need to add additional constraints, but Xcode can do this for you.

Comment: I've tried this way. But so much frustration, when I tried to keep relative positions of the subviews in comparison to the parent view, which again is a subview of another view or the view of the UIViewController. Many issues of the auto layout occur. Do you know any tutorial for that? I google around and see only simple cases related to screen rotation.

Comment: Your case is interesting, I hadn't realised that there are (I haven't seen them or checked myself) problems with auto-layout and animations. I'll setup a test project as soon as I can and try it out myself. As for tutorials, the one I learnt from was on Lynda.com by Simon Allardice. I'm surprised that you can't find a good blog post on it though.